# Send data from one console application to another

Tags: message

I am working on a project that will essentially run each part of a program on a complete separate computer. Reason for this because these are data servers, gaining data from a target program launched on the main users desktop. (very CPU intensive)

The application just needs to be able to send data and things like this across a network. 
One is a Console app and the other is a C# made operating system(Technically WPF, but replaces windows and just leaves a kernel).

So how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can use Sockets for communication eachother.

Comment: does it connect via IP address? @VasoBeruashvili

Comment: Yes you can use IP of receiver/receivers to send information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both applications are in C#, the easiest way will be to use Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712(v=vs.90).aspx

It allows you call remote methods as though they are just plain local methods.